# What is the failure mode of a seat in a Symmons shower valve?

Tags: plumbing, shower, plumbing-fixture

I feel like I'm throwing parts at a problem without knowing what they do. I've ordered a cartridge, seats, and specialty tools and will probably fully rebuild the valve, but I don't like not knowing which of the two parts is causing my exact problem.

I'm wondering, what symptoms a Symmons valve would show if it had worn valve seats?

In my searches, I've found a lot of "how to replace", not a lot of "why to replace."

I couldn't find any troubleshooting docs from Symmons, so I suppose we're relying on our own tribal knowledge at this point! The only hint that I found talks about seats being the cause for a dripping shower head after the valve is turned off.

Comment: My particular problem is that the valve has become "sloppy," you have to go past warm then back towards cold to get the right temp. Straight to warm stays cold.

Comment: Main symptom of worn valve seat is leaking, they stop sealing well.

Comment: Think your cartridge is the problem.  Depending on the age the seats might be getting worn also.  Would check them after cleaning and compare to the new seats.  If in good condition can leave the old seats in, but if not it will be a good time to replace as you have it apart anyway.